What's the correct data structure for an ordered list of checkboxes in .NET Framework?
I'm building an web app where one of the features is our employees can submit or save a checklist. It's simply a list of checkboxes (not in a form, just in a table) that needs to be POST'd to the server. I use jQuery to get all the checkboxes in the table (as well as ancillary data for each, such as an optional "group" that they're in that I validate on the server, for example). Each checkbox has a unique key that I would like to index by. As such, from jQuery, I'm submitting a nested object- an outer object containing the keys of the checkboxes, and an inner object with checkbox information. It looks something like this:
{
  "ExampleKey1": {
    "Checked": "true",
    "Group": "ExampleGroup"
  },
  "ExampleKey2": {
    "Checked": "false",
    "Group": "ExampleGroup"
  }
}

Now, I need to bind this data to a .NET action method, but I also need to keep it in order. This is so that when we serialize it to XML, it stays consistent and human-readable (e.g., "ExampleKey2" isn't before "ExampleKey1" and the checkbox is saved in the same order). Dictionaries are not guaranteed to be in the same order (even though it will be in this case, since no items are removed), so my approach was to use an OrderedDictionary. Microsoft does include an OrderedDictionary in System.Collections.Specialized, but for whatever reason, they don't include a generic override...
As per this stackoverflow answer, I decided that a good approach would be to copy Microsoft's own, internal implementation of an OrderedDictionary<T>, which left me with a final parameter of OrderedDictionary<string, OrderedDictionary<string, string>> (I later realized that the inner one technically doesn't have to be ordered). My boss, though, does not like this approach since we're adding a custom data structure and he finds it harder to read and more confusing.
So, my question is, what data structure can I use to appropriately bind this data (i.e., in order like a List<T>, but accessible by key like a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>)? To my knowledge, System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary can't be bound with the default model binders.
There are a few approaches I can think of. I could maybe do some kind of custom model binder for a class. My boss said I can use a Queue or a List, but I feel that this might not be the right structure since I would prefer the ease of using an array accessor, while also being able to iterate through the values if I don't know the key. One final solution that my boss said is that I can add an "Order" parameter to the checkboxes and sort by that, but to me that's a lot of manual work with possibility of human error, and still doesn't solve the issue of being able to easily access by key, unless I used a LINQ query.
There are many approaches that could work, but I want to ensure that I'm using the right tool for the job so that it's organized, readable, and easy to extend if we work on it in the future.
